# How to get values only from a two dimensional JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I need to convert JSON to Array. I tried using `map` . It works with simple JSON, but doesn't work with two dimensional JSON

```
<script>

var json = `{ "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3 }`;
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
var values = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { return obj[key]; });
alert("This Works " + JSON.stringify(values)); 

var json2 = `[{ "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3 },{ "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3 },{ "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3 }]`;
var obj2 = JSON.parse(json2);
var values2 = Object.keys(obj2).map(function (key) { return obj2[key]; });
alert("This Doesn't Work " + JSON.stringify(values2));

</script>
```

This is a test case. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This isn't JSON, this is an array filled with objects.

Comment: You think you're getting keys, but actually, you're getting the indexes.

Comment: which are... keys. :shrug:

Comment: As one of the answers, you have to treat it as an array. Eitherway I don't think in that the final approach you are looking for it will be more usefull to have an array of 'values' rather than the actual array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second object is an array, so you need to use it as is.

An alternative is using the function `reduce` to get the objects and concatenate the values using the function `concat`.

A recommendation is to use the function `Object.values` to avoid the mapping process.

```js
var json = `{ "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3 }`;
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
var values = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
  return obj[key];
});
console.log("This Works " + JSON.stringify(values));

var json2 = `[{ "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3 },{ "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3 },{ "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3 }]`,
    obj2 = JSON.parse(json2),
    values2 = obj2.reduce((a, c) => [...a, Object.values(c)], []);
    
console.log("This now Works " + JSON.stringify(values2));
```

Comment: Thank you. But this returns a one dimensional array `[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]`. How can I preserve the two dimensional nature? Expected result: `[{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}]`

Comment: @john that's not a valid js object.

Comment: i mean 2d array. `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`

Answer (score 1):

You have to process the outer array first with the map function and later you have to use Object.values, finally you must use flat in order to have one dimensional array

```
var newArray = obj2.map(function (element) { return Object.values(element); }).flat();
```